# Civic knocking while pushing harder and acceleration lag

Tags: civic, acceleration, engine-knock

I have civic 98 with D16Y4 engine with automatic transmission. It knocks while  pushing gas harder during high revs. I'm currently using ron 92 and I tried ron 97 but faced knocking on all I even tried shell V-Power but result remains same. I guess it's engine timing issue?
Also whenever I instantly push gas engine take 2-3seconds lag then it respond. Any expert opinion are welcome

Comment: When did you last have it serviced? Have you had the timing checked?

Comment: Serviced a month ago. Last Sunday I got engine timing belt changed but I faced this issue before replacing timing belt. No not checked engine timing.

Comment: Could be an air leak ? it'd result in weak mixture whcih burns more quickly, resulting in advanced timing. Air leak would be iafter air filter or bolts on inlet manifold. note that it could be many other things too

Answer (score 1):

All issues were due to bad ignition timing after setting up timing belt according to service manual engine's power restored and also acceleration lag is gone. Thanks everyone for taking part in solving issues :)